# Maya to blender pivot point location changes

Tags: export, import, transform-orientation

I am new at Blender and I am trying to import a file that has multiple objects and some of them have the pivot point set at a specific place for them to rotate properly (car doors, windows, etc.)
The problem is that when I export with FBX, all the pivot points go to the origin and I can not find a way to make them import properly.
I also tried exporting from Maya as DAE.fbx but even though the file seems to export fine (I can re-import it into Maya without problem) when I try in Blender, nothing gets imported.
I hope I am missing something simple and there is an easy fix for that.
Thanks a lot for any help!

Leo

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I noticed that the objects causing trouble had their transformations frozen in Maya. Once I unfroze objects transformations & exported to Blender again, everything was working as expected. I found this handy [script](http://pozeststar.blogspot.com/2012/02/mel-script-unfreezing-transformations.html) to unfreeze objects transformations in Maya. Hope this helps anyone going through the same issue in the future.